# I am trying to launch an ec2 instance(i.e. ubuntu ami) using aws-cli and i want to copy my code from a s3 bucket that i have created earlier

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

This is the Command i am using to spin up my ec2 instance :

`aws ec2 run-instances --image-id *ubuntu image id* --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name new_instance --security-group-ids mysecuity --user-data file://aws.txt`

My aws.txt file contents :

```
`#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y apache2 php7.0 php7.0-curl php7.0-cli
sudo service apache2 start
sudo apt-get install -y python3 python-pip
sudo apt-get update && sudo pip install --upgrade --user awscli
mkdir ~/.aws && cd ~/.aws
touch credentials && touch config
echo "[default]" > credentials
echo "aws_access_key_id = *id here*" >> credentials
echo "aws_secret_access_key = *secret key*" >> credentials
echo "[default]" > config
echo "output = json" >> config
echo "region = ap-south-1" >> config`enter code here`
sudo aws s3 sync s3://*bucket name* var/www/html`
```

But only apache2 and php are getting installed. And mkdir isnt working and awscli isn't being installed and because of that my s3 bucket code isnt being synced with my ebs volume.

Comment: Please check the output of `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` as mentioned in the documentation : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

Comment: It doesn't look like your user data ever ran. It could be that these packages came by default in your AMI. As per this (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) AWS documentation: Also, these instructions are intended for use with Amazon Linux, and the commands and directives may not work for other Linux distributions. For more information about other distributions, such as their support for cloud-init, see their specific documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be throwing an error on `mkdir ~/.aws && cd ~/.aws` line because "~" refers to different location sometime Instead use `mkdir /home/*username here*/.aws && cd /home/*username here*/.aws`. It should work and try n use sudo with last aws line.

Comment: In general, if you want to access AWS services from an EC2 instance, you should use a role, and not deploy credentials to the instance.  So everything from mkdir to the last echo are not needed.